# Get text from current element in autoplay carousel using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using Wow carousel in WordPress, and I want to get the text in the current element in the slider.
In Wow Carousel, the current slide takes the class center
My problem with the autoplay slider, the value stored in my variable doesn't change automatically
How can I fire the function when the class center is added automatically every time?
My code

```
<div id="testimonial-slider-5781" class="owl-carousel owl-loaded owl-drag">
<div class="owl-item active" style="width: 235.333px; margin-right: 15px;"><div class="testimonial-5781">
<h3> text </h3>
</div>
<div class="owl-item active" style="width: 235.333px; margin-right: 15px;"><div class="testimonial-5781">
<h3> text </h3>
</div>
<div class="owl-item active center" style="width: 235.333px; margin-right: 15px;"><div class="testimonial-5781">
<h3> text </h3>
</div>
<div class="owl-item" style="width: 235.333px; margin-right: 15px;"><div class="testimonial-5781">
<h3> text </h3>
</div>
</div>
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    function myFunction() {
    let title = jQuery( "#testimonial-slider-5781 .center .testimonial-5781 h4" ).text();
    jQuery("#service-title h3").text(title);
    }   
    jQuery('.owl-prev').click(function(){
        myFunction();
    });
    jQuery('.owl-next').click(function(){
        myFunction();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to `translated.owl.carousel` event since it's triggered everytime carousel is translated, that would mean it's also triggered when class center is added to current slide.

Here is an example, do adapt to your own code as appropriate.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  function myFunction() {
    let title = jQuery("#testimonial-slider-5781 .center .testimonial-5781 h3").text();
    jQuery("#service-title h3").text(title);
  }   
  jQuery("#testimonial-slider-5781").on("translated.owl.carousel", function() {
    myFunction();
  });
});
```